# Android target SDK moved from 26 to 28, error: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

On our project, we have some downtime and decided to update the project target SDK version from API 26 to API 28. The project builds and works somewhat fine. The problem that we have is that we get this error when we switch back to a fragment that is in the back stack:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call `removeView()` on the child's parent first.

We have a class called `BaseNavigationController` that is a fragment and manages our nested fragments. We use the `getChildFragmentManager` and we set the `setCustomAnimations` with enter, exit, popEnter and popExit values.

The error "disappears" when we set the duration of all the animation to the exact same length. But that it persist if we remove the `setCustomAnimations` from the transaction.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(enter, exit, popEnter, popExit)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .replace(R.id.main_container, controller, tag)
                .commit();
```

I haven't found any proper solution to this problem. One hack is to remove the view in the `onDestroyView` method in the base fragment. But then we get an empty screen on the enter animation from the back stack. The other one is that we use the `getFragmentManager` method but then the fragment nesting doesn`t work correctly.